# Eclipse Javadoc Background Overrides Default

Tags: java, eclipse

My default workspace on Eclipse set the Javadoc Background color to black and it is impossible to read the text:

[Javadoc black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT40y.png)

I have already tried to "restore defaults" at **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts**, but it works until I close the workspace. Next time I open it again, the problem returns:

[Preferences Javadoc Background overrides default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNHs6.png)

I have tried to find the file inside **workspace\.metadata\.plugins** folder that set this configuration, but I didn't find. I also tried to find other solutions, but I only found solutions for Ubuntu OS, and I am on Windows 7 with an Oxygen.3A Eclipse.

Has anyone faced this problem?

Thanks in advance.

PS1.: New workspaces comes without the error.

PS2.: I work with lots of workspaces at work, so creating new ones is not an option, because it will take hours to reorganize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you lose your current workspace setting for background color whenever you reopen the workspace perhaps [Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) has stored a configuration setting for background color for that workspace (black in your case), and that is being used on startup to override your most recent setting.

To resolve:

- Select **Window > Preferences > Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder**
- Check **Record into** and select **Workspace** from the droplist.
- Enter **Javadoc.backgroundColor** in the search field and then check the entry that is listed, so that your screen looks like this:

[image: OomphSetting]

- Click **Apply and Close**.
- Select **Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Color and Fonts**, select **Java > Javadoc background** and then click **Edit...** to choose the background color you want.
- Click **Apply and Close** then restart Eclipse. After restarting you should see that your most recent color change is still being used.
- Optionally, uncheck **Record into** so that Oomph doesn't record further configuration changes.

(I am not confident that this is necessarily the solution because it implies that someone had previously set the Javadoc background color to black as part of the Oomph configuration for the workspace, and that is not easy to do unintentionally.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I tried to find **Javadoc.backgroundColor** at that page, and it Eclipse didn't find it. Is there any other places to find it?

Comment: I just tried another approach:
- At **Preference Recorder**, I clicked the **Initialize** button and unchecked the **General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts**;
- Closed the workspace;
- Reopened it;
Now it keeps saying that the color is being overriden, but now it has the default colors, instead of the previous black.
I don't know if this is correct, but it worked.
The **Initialize** button now, is unclickable.

Comment: @VictorAugustoFariasDinis It makes sense that **Initialize** is now unclickable since there is no need to visit all the **Preferences** pages more than once. It's good that you have it working, but I don't understand why you could not find **Javadoc.backgroundColor** since it is clearly present in your second screenshot  - perhaps try searching for just **Javadoc** or **background**. Also, are you using a color theme?

Comment: @VictorAugustoFariasDinis Also, FYI it looks like the color preferences are stored in file "{Eclipse workspace}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs". After changing the _Javadoc background_ color for my workspace I have a setting for **org.eclipse.jdt.ui.Javadoc.backgroundColor** in that file.

Comment: skomisa Replying to your first comment: I also find strange not find the **Javadoc.backgroundColor** property. I have searched for just Javadoc, and I found 3 properties, none of them referring to the background color. I'm not using any color theme, I just change it to the classic theme, for performance purposes.

Comment: Replying to your second comment: this property didn't appear on my  "{Eclipse workspace}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs" file. I'll try uninstalling this Eclipse instance, maybe it is a bug for this version.

Comment: @victoraugustofd OK. Unresolved Eclipse [Bug 507632 - Oomph setup for SWT breaks Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507632) may be relevant: _"...the NPE is exposed because the color's default color does not exist. The fix is to use the default-default color of black. Now with the NPE resolved, what I end up with in the UI is completely broken Javadoc hovers as both foreground and background are black"_. So perhaps you can't find **org.eclipse.jdt.ui.Javadoc.backgroundColor** due to an error during the install of Eclipse? Reinstalling Eclipse may fix this.

Comment: skomisa, I figured out whats is going on. I think it is really a bug for the Classical Theme on Eclipse Oxygen 3A. I changed the theme for the default, and the error disappeared. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Hi Victor, please make than an answer. I had the same issue so this was useful, thanks (I had to restart Eclipse, BTW).

Comment: I agree with @victoraugustofd, I changed from the Classic theme to another theme, restarted Eclipse and it works now. I'm on 2018-12 eclipse.

Comment: @Halfstop Since you are the third poster with the same solution, could you consider posting your approach as an answer? I was never convinced that my answer resolved this (_"I am not confident that this is necessarily the solution..."_ ). The OP probably should not have accepted it, but he has not logged in for several months. I'll be happy to upvote your answer, and delete my own. I think that would be more helpful for the community than having an accepted but unsatisfactory answer.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem on Eclipse 2018-12 by changing to a theme other than "Classic." Once I did that and restarted Eclipse, it looked like it should.

**Preferences**->**General**->**Appearance**.

Make sure Enable theming is checked.

Select a different theme from Classic and restart Eclipse.